# Use Paypal webhooks simulator in nodejs

Tags: node.js, paypal

I'm try to send events from webhooks simulator to test my app I provided the URL and select the event from dropdown and click send it show **event is successfully queued ...** waiting few minutes but not got anything to that URL. Can you please let me know why it's not sending anything I tried different **events** but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the webhook URL is, we can't comment specifically, but typical problems are:

1. Non-standard port (must be https on 443)
2. Firewall issue (must be publicly accessible)
3. A domain PayPal cannot resolve or connect to (try a different domain or IP address)

Comment: I'm using `ngrok` with `localhost` it is working over https I'm able to access this URL successfully I tried to access it from post man and send some data to that URL and it working fine but simulator is not working

Comment: URL look like this `https://f22812310983.ngrok.io/paypal/subscription-webhook` but each time you start new ngrok URL host change but this is not a problem because I enter the same URL which is active at that time

Comment: If you can't get it to work, try your testing using some service other than ngrok to localhost